# How to dynamically scroll NSScrollView based on dragged control

Tags: macos, cocoa, cocoa-design-patterns

I have an NSScrollView that contains a Drawing.   Drawing is a subclass of NSView and is a drop target.   I have another class called dragBox which is an NSBox and a drag source.   I want to be able to dynamically change the size of the Drawing to accommodate dragging the dragBox outside the size of the NSScrollView.   Currently I define a "hot area" in the NSScrollView's content view that automatically scrolls.   The problem is that when I drop the dragBox, it doesn't drop it in the virtual space that was just created.   It drops it relative to the size of the viewport.   Here's the code.

```
@implementation Drawing


-(NSDragOperation)draggingUpdated:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender // validate
{
NSLog(@"Updated");
_drawHintPoint = [sender draggedImageLocation];

if ([sender draggingLocation].x > [[self superview] bounds].size.width - 30)
{
    NSRect scrollRect = NSMakeRect(0,0, [self bounds].size.width + 30, [self bounds].size.height) ;
    [self setFrame:scrollRect];
    _drawHintPoint = NSMakePoint([self bounds].size.width + 30, [sender draggingLocation].y);
    [self scrollPoint:_drawHintPoint];

}





 return NSDragOperationEvery;

}





-(BOOL) prepareForDragOperation:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)sender
{
NSLog(@"Prepared");
return YES;

}
- (BOOL)performDragOperation:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender {

NSLog(@"Move Box");
NSPoint pt = _drawHintPoint;
pt.x = pt.x - 32;
pt.y = pt.y - 32;
[[_ico box] setFrameOrigin:pt];
return YES;
}


- (NSDragOperation)draggingEntered:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender {
NSLog(@"Drag Entered");


_drawHintPoint = NSMakePoint(0, 0);



return NSDragOperationEvery;

}
```

How do I drop the dragBox so that it drops it in the virtual space provided?

Bruce

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

In draggingUpdated, this did the trick:

```
 _drawHintPoint = [[self superview] convertPoint:[sender draggingLocation] fromView:nil];
```

You need to convert the dragging location to coordinates in the scroll view.  [self superview] in the above line refers to the NSClipRect.